# Kafka acl without kerberos

Tags: ssl, authentication, access-control-list, kafka

I'm trying to set up a single kafka server with certificate authentication and access controls based on those certificates without the bother of setting up a kerberos service.

Setting upp the certificate authentication is easy. But I enable the acl module in the config try to connect with a producer and get access denied errors, OK, I grant access and now I get a "leader not available" error. Disabling the acl module makes everything work again.

Is this possible or is it a requirement to use kerberos?

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the problem , it seems support ssl-only + acl , you can try it
  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.kafka.user/12619

Comment: It is better to quote the referenced solution here, and use the link as a citation.

Comment: @fann could you update the link to the solution as gmane.org was shut down recently hence the link doesn't work anymore